# Trying to use Powershell to run four instances of modelling software, check if one stops and start another

Tags: powershell

We have a lot of air quality modelling to do and I have been asked to write some script that will run multiple instances of the software concurrently, starting a new process if it finds there are less than four processes running already (four is the max number of instances the software allows).

I've been given the following script that someone had already and  slightly adapted it.

```
function waitadms($p){

do{

    $ProcessActive = Get-Process $p[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}
until ($ProcessActive.count -lt $p[1])

    " done"

}


#waitadms("ADMSUrbanModel",4)

#break
$scn = "C:\Models\Test"


$upls = ls * -Recurse  -include *.upl  -path $scn 
$upls | foreach{$_.name;waitadms("ADMSUrbanModel",4);Start-Sleep -s 10;&("C:\Program Files (x86)\CERC\ADMSRoad\ADMSUrbanModel.exe") /e2 /ADMSRoads $_.fullname}
```

the `$upls` variable is a list of the models that are needed to run and the function `waitadms` is supposed to run a new instance of the model for each entry in the list.

If I run the script, it opens the first four models, but then when its found one finished, it fails to open a new one. However, the Powershell window prints the next entry in the list, so its obviously finding the right file. It just doesn't open the actual software (ADMSUrbanModel.exe) like it did for the first four.

The code may be a bit dodgy, I just don't know. But it seems funny that it opens the first four instances correctly then fails when one finishes.

Comment: Do not call PowerShell functions using `( )` after the function name or commas between arguments (this is valid syntactically, but wrong semantically) -- i.e., your syntax should be `waitadms "ADMSUrbanModel" 4`, not `waitadms("ADMSUrbanModel",4)`. This also applies to the argument following the `&` operator. Also, your `waitadms` function doesn't define a second argument.

Comment: I see part of the confusion; you are passing an array to your function instead of using separate parameters. You should definitely use parameters as it greatly clarifies the intent on both sides of the function call.

Comment: What do you mean by the function not defining a second argument? Is the array the list of models specified by `$upls`? how would you replace that with parameters?

Comment: Run `help about_Functions` and read on.